# Binding HeaderTemplate in MVVM Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM-style menu which is done using 2 viewmodels and a style:

ViewModel:

```
public class CommandViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isOpen;
    private IEnumerable<object> _items;
    private UIElement _placementTarget;



    /// <summary>
    /// the command itself
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// parameter object for the command
    /// </summary>
    public Object CommandParameter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// header string for the command, e.g. in menus
    /// </summary>
    public string Header { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// oprional Tooltip for the command, e.g. on buttons
    /// </summary>
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// optional icon for the command, e.g. on buttons or in menus
    /// </summary>
    public ControlTemplate Icon { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// optional item list. e.g. submenu entries.
    /// For a submenu set the command to null and fill the Items list with CommandViewModels or other ViewModels you have a template for
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Object> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            Command = new RelayCommand<UIElement>((param) =>
            {
                PlacementTarget = param;
                IsOpen = true;
            });
        }
    }


    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return _isOpen;
        }
        set
        {
            _isOpen = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsOpen);
        }
    }


    public virtual bool IsSeparator { get { return false; } }


    public UIElement PlacementTarget
    {
        get { return _placementTarget; }
        set
        {
            _placementTarget = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => PlacementTarget);
        }
    }
}
```

Separator:

```
public class SeparatorViewModel : CommandViewModel
{
    public override bool IsSeparator
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" x:Key="MvvmMenuItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Tooltip}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator}" Value="true">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{StaticResource WindowButtonsBackground}" Margin="3,5"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<MenuItem Header="Device" ItemsSource="{Binding DevicesMenu}" Visibility="{Binding IsDevicesMenuVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MvvmMenuItemStyle}"/>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

I bind the items of my (top) menuitem to a list of CommandViewModels, which can have children, a Header, a Command, CommandParameter etc...
The IsOpen Prop is for when i use it with ContextMenus, which is not the case here.

This was working great so far.

Now I want to add and Icon to each entry. I thought i could just add a HeaderTemplate to my Style, which shows the Icon and the Header text, but it doesn't work, nothing shows.

This is the HeaderTemplate setter I added to the style:

```
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl Template="{Binding Icon}" Width="26"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Header}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Note: My Icons are ControlTemlates, which contain vector graphics in XAML, so I can't use the 'Icon'-Property of MenuItem. The Menu-Entries show no Text and no Icon as soon as I add the HeaderTemplate to the Style. I know that the HeaderTemplate is applied, because if i increase the width of the icon ContentControl (e.g. from 26 to 260) my menus get wider. This means I have a problem with my bindings in the HeaderTemplate.

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings for the icon and header are not in the visual tree where there is easy access to the datacontext (*the one needed which inherits up to the data context with the VM*) and other items.  The bindings will need to be a relative source path instead.

Here is an approximation of pathing used to access the main data context which has the VM:

```
Text="{Binding Header, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                               AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"/>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! This is what made it work: `Text="{Binding DataContext.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"`. It also works without the `DataContext.` but then it binds to the Header-Property of the MenuItem and not to the ViewModel's Prop.

Comment: @JCH2k There are a few controls where one doesn't have access to the main VM, so one has to keep this trick in mind for other controls/templates.